# Azure App Service .Net backend - Error when executing stored procedure query

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm working with a .NET backend with Azure App Service. I'm trying to execute a stored procedure via a SQL query but I get the following error:

> Procedure or function 'IndividualAverages' expects parameter '@userId', which was not supplied

I'm not sure why I get this error when I have explicitly supplied all the parameters, including the `@userId` above.

This is my code:

```
var paramId = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@userId", user_accountId.Trim());
var paramDateStart = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StartDate",newStartDate.ToUniversalTime());
var paramDateEnd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@EndDate", newEndDate.ToUniversalTime());

var userAverage = context.IndividualAverage.SqlQuery("EXEC dbo.IndividualAverages" , paramId, paramDateStart, paramDateEnd).ToList();
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: "EXEC dbo.IndividualAverage**s**" (note the s) and "IndividualAverage" are not the same SP

Comment: Alex, I edited my question. That was an oversight. I rectified that. They are the same in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. All I needed to do was add the parameters in the SQL query statement.

```
var userAverage = context.IndividualAverage.SqlQuery("EXEC dbo.IndividualAverages @userId,@StartDate,@EndDate" , paramId, paramDateStart, paramDateEnd).ToList();
```